# Error: request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

I am passing pointer to pointer to `typedef struct` to the function. When I try to change the content of `typedef struct`, it gives me following error:

> request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union
>   }

The code:

```
typedef struct _tempStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}TempStruct;

void _function(TempStruct ** param)
{
    TempStruct *temp = *param;
    temp -> a = 5; //no error
    *param -> a = 6; //error: request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union
}
```

[Here is the link of code on ideone](http://ideone.com/57sObT).

What I am missing?

Comment: `(*param)->a` probably

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` has a higher precedence than that of `*`(indirection), so

```
*param -> a = 6;
```

should be

```
(*param)->a = 6;
```

Answer (score 4):

The arrow `->` operator binds more tightly than the `*` does.  You need:

```
(*param)->a = 6;
```

Don't put spaces around `->` or `.`; they bind very tightly.  Spaces mark you as a neophyte.